# Not using stochasstic integral how to prove $E\int_0^T W^2(t)dt<+\infty$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Can anyone help me to prove this?

Suppose $W_t$ ~ $N(0,t)$, then not using stochasstic integral (or anything related with Ito) how to prove $E\int_0^T W^2(t)dt<+\infty$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Fubini's Theorem (the integrand is positive):
\begin{align}
E\int_0^TW^2(t)dt=\int_0^T(EW^2(t))dt=\int_0^Ttdt=T^2/2<\infty.
\end{align}